# Is Godaddy API returning bad results?

Tags: rest, api, godaddy-api

I'm trying to figure out if I'm doing something wrong, or if GoDaddy is just returning bad results.

When I check the domain availability on their API sandbox, domains show up as "true" or available.

But then, when I check on the front end of GoDaddy, they show as "taken"

For example, if I use the following get request, GoDaddy API returns as "available"

```
https://api.ote-godaddy.com/v1/domains/available?domain=facebookchat.com&checkType=FAST&forTransfer=false
```

Returned JSON

```
{
  "available": true,
  "currency": "USD",
  "definitive": true,
  "domain": "facebookchat.com",
  "period": 1,
  "price": 7490000
}
```

But if I check on the front end here, it comes back as "taken"

```
https://www.godaddy.com/domainsearch/find?checkAvail=1&tmskey=&domainToCheck=facebookchat.com
```

Photo from official API showing domain *available*:

[image: Photo from official API showing domain *available*]

Front end results showing domain NOT *available*:

[image: Front end results showing domain NOT *available*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say their API is unreliable. I just tested it for `domain=getpostman.com` and it reports `"available": true` even though it most certainly is not.

```
{
    "available": true,
    "currency": "USD",
    "definitive": true,
    "domain": "getpostman.com",
    "period": 1,
    "price": 10690000
}
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains#model-DomainAvailableResponse), the "available" and "definitive" values are supposed to indicate that they are absolutely sure about whether or not the domain name is available.

> **DomainAvailableResponse**
>
> available*    boolean    Whether or not the domain name is available
>
> definitive*   boolean    Whether or not the available answer has been definitively verified with the registry

Comment: "The registry could still provide false positives in their results." - this is a quote from an email from GoDaddy support. Also, the poster is using the test environment which nobody expects to return real data.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that you're using the test environment and that's why you get different results than their website. The OTE is probably a snapshot of the real database at some point and they just kept it that way thus the resulting difference. Try to switch to the production environment and compare results again.

Another side of this is the definitive variable returned by the availability check API call. The documentation vaguely states "Whether or not the available answer has been definitively verified with the registry" as clarification for the said variable.

Edit: you're definitely using the test environment, just saw the URI on your screenshot.